# Download existing file from IIS results in File does not exists (404)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a full working web site that i ported to a new hosting company.

In some pages i have links to PDF on the server (they do exist!)

On the old server no problem.
On the new one when user clicks on the link : error 404 file does not exist...

Should i look in the web.config ? i don't know where to start
thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

Start from the file read permissions.

You need to read the log files, or the event viewer to see whats really is the problem.

Comment: if is mutualized hosting, then maybe there are restrictions and filter, that you need to check on your server control. Maybe they not allow every extension by default (because everything I belive that is filtering throw his engine) and you need to add the pdf extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably as simple as the files not being in the exact relative location to the page that they used to be in - e.g. there was a folder /pdfs in the root of the web where all the files were, now they are just in the root folder, and the links were not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You've not said which version of IIS you're using. However for IIS5, this has been answered over at ServerFault -- see https://serverfault.com/questions/79094/serve-pdf-fies-in-iis

It should be similar for IIS6. It's possible your hosting provider may have revoked the MIME type so IIS no longer recognises it.

What you may end up needing to do if your hosting company isn't forthcoming is write a "file provider" page that takes the file to download on the query string (obviously with some sanity checking so folk can't request any old file), then just writes it out, bypassing what IIS would do normally.

Comment: i have added the extension for no success...
Is medium trust has something to do  ?